# How to get app's price from app store?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My app contains a list of "related apps". I'm linking each app entry to the App Store so its easier for the user to download them.
To improve the user experience I want to show the **price** for each app entry, so the user doesn't have to enter the app store to find out the price.
I've found the class `SKProductsRequest` which allows to request product information from the App Store, but it seems that it can only be used for *In-App Purchases* not to retrieve the information of an *app*.

Can `SKProductsRequest` be used to retrieve information of an app?
If `SKProductsRequest` can't be used. ¿Can I retrieve the localized price for an app from the App Store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a call to iTunes' Search API and you'll get the data you need.

More at - http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

For example here's how the get the details for the Yelp app by iTunes ID - https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=284910350

Comment: To retrieve the `formattedPrice` in the correct locale you must include the `country` parameter in the request, for example: https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=450542233&country=ES

Comment: Is there perhaps any way to additionally get a date WHEN this current price was set?